# How to make a Kivy app as an Android launcher / home screen

Tags: android, python, android-intent, kivy, launcher

I am trying to make a single purpose device which should only show a Kivy app as its sole purpose.

According to various documentations, I have put intent filters in buildozer spec using a `intent_filters.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have checked the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `dist` folder and it seems to create a Intent Filter entry, however it only takes the first two parameters:

```
...    
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <intent-filter>
...
```

The application compiles normally, but I do not get any option to set it as a Home screen/Launcher

Am I missing something?

Comment: The text read from the file pointed to by `android.manifest.intent_filters` is read and inserted directly into the manifest; the text is not manipulated in any way. Please double check that you are pointing to the right intent_filters.xml file.

Comment: *kicks self in the head* - looks like all I had to do was to add add `%(source.dir)s/` so that it looks like `android.manifest.intent_filters = %(source.dir)s/intent_filters.xml` Thanks a lot @ryan-p